# Fastest way to check if an ID in your dataframe exists in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have large pandas dataframe (around million rows) and a list of id-s (length of array is 100,000). For each id in df1 I have to check if that id is in my list (called `special`) and flag it accordingly:

```
df['Segment'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x in special else np.nan)
```

problem is that this is extremely slow, as for million id-s lambda expression checks if that id is in a list of 100,000 entries. Is there a faster way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you see [`When should I ever want to use apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

Use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
 df['Segment'] = df['ID'].isin(special).astype(int)
```

We can also use [`Series.view`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df['Segment'] = df['ID'].isin(special).view('uint8')
```

or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['Segment'] = np.where(df['ID'].isin(special),1 ,0)
```